# The metaphor of fried chicken

Tags: meaning-in-context

From *To Kill a Mockingbird*:

> “Well, Indian-heads — well, they come from the Indians. They’re real strong magic, they make you have good luck. **Not like fried chicken when you’re not lookin’ for it**, but things like long life ‘n’ good health, ‘n’ passin’ six-weeks tests... these are real valuable to somebody. I’m gonna put em in my trunk.”

What does the sentence mean here?

Comment: Those would be Indian Head cents which were struck from 1859 to 1909. It is mentioned before that they are from 1906 and 1900, in which there were ~96 million and ~67 million produced respectfully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that the good luck conferred by Indian-heads isn't just trivial good luck, like having fried chicken (usually served on relatively festive occasions) for dinner when you weren't expecting it<sup>†</sup>, but *important* good luck, like long life and good health, and passing a six-weeks test<sup>‡</sup>.

---

<sup>†</sup> *Look for* may have in Southern dialects the sense *expect*.

<sup>‡</sup>In Alabama schools grades are given out every six weeks, so for a child the 'six-weeks test' is a major milestone in the school year.)